# Upgrading to Symfony 2.2 RC2 causes mapping errors

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2

I have just upgraded my Symfony's project version from 2.1 to 2.2 RC2 and started seeing some mapping errors that did not appear on 2.1. My entire mapping seems to throw errors. There's an example:

These are my two entities.

1.

```
MyBundle\Entity\Usuario:
    type: entity
    table: usuario
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
            column: co_usuario
    fields:
        [...]
    oneToMany:
        historicos:
            targetEntity: Historico
            mappedBy: id
    [...]
```

2.

```
MyBundle\Entity\Historico:
    type: entity
    table: historico
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
            column: co_historico
    fields:
        [...]
    manyToOne:
        coUsuario:
            targetEntity: Usuario
            inversedBy: historicos
            joinColumn:
                name: co_usuario
                referencedColumnName: co_usuario
        [...]
```

And these are the errors I'm getting:

> The association MyBundle\Entity\Usuario#historicos refers to the
>   owning side field MyBundle\Entity\Historico#id which is not defined as
>   association.
>
> The association MyBundle\Entity\Usuario#historicos refers
>   to the owning side field MyBundle\Entity\Historico#id which does not
>   exist.

My previous composer.json (from version 2.1, in which everything was working fine) had these versions of doctrine:

```
[...]
"doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
[...]
```

And Symfony 2.2 RC2 comes with these versions of Doctrine:

```
[...]
"doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
[...]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, it seems pretty much like everything we see on doctrine's mapping docs. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation error is right.

There's nothing wrong with that: we just improved Doctrine's runtime validator to catch such exceptions also when metadata is loaded.

Here's how your YAML should actually be changed:

```
MyBundle\Entity\Usuario:
    [...]
    oneToMany:
        historicos:
            targetEntity: Historico
            mappedBy: coUsuario
    [...]
```

I basically fixed the `oneToMany` association `mappedBy` property to point at the correct field.